# Custom conditional statments? Is this possible?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, overloading

Is it possible to write your own conditional statements or overload current ones? (Like the if short hand - `?`)

I have done some research and can't find anything. Something I have in mind:

```
do
{
   //Run Application
}if(...)//Only If variables are initialised
```

If this is possible, how would I go about doing so in c++?

Comment: Not really clear what you want. Show an example of expected functionality.

Comment: If you need to overload `if` you're solving the problem wrong.

Comment: Some Use case of what you'd like to achieve will make more sense..

Comment: What would `do { ... } if (...)` even mean?!

Comment: isn't `do { ... }  if (...)` the same as `if (...) { ... }`?

Comment: Added an example of what I am thinking...

Comment: Perhaps `do { ... } if (...)` should be `do { ... } while (...)`, which exists in the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do
{
   //Run Application
}if(...)//Only If variables are initialised
```

would translate to

```
if ( condition )
{
   //run application
}
```

So why not just do that?

It's not possible to create new operators, and it's not possible to overload the **ternary operator `?:`**.

You could mess around with the preprocessor, but you'll end up having less clear code than just using a regular `if`.

```
#define RUNIF(condition, statement) \
if ( condition ) \
{                \
   statement();  \
}
```

and call it like:

```
RUNIF(condition, RunApplication())
```

but personally, I'd hate to see this in production code.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I see now why a do(){}if(){} is 'stupid' and a simple 'if' does that for me anyway.

Comment: And yes, RUNIF(condition, RunApplication()) would be rather awful :S

Answer (score 2):

In pure C++, you can only overload existing operators, not create new ones.

That said, nothing prevents you from playing with the preprocessor *or* your custom preprocessor (like Qt does).

Comment: Not all, for example you can't overload `?:`, which is kind of the only one that would make sense for a conditional...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I didn't say *all*, I said you can only change stuff that preexists, not create new.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of the overloadable operators [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++).  So you could overload conditionals like `&&` and `||` (although not recommended), but not `?:`

Other keywords like `do`/`while`/`if` are not overloadable, so you cannot write

```
do {
  ...
} if()
```

in a way that compiles (sans preprocessor macros)

but you could do:

```
if(...) {
  while(true) {
    ...
  }
}
```

note: no overloading, just plain reorganization of code

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you put `if()` you could use `while` and also applyed there condition - just as in plain `if`, for example:

```
do
{
   Object x = getObject(); 
}while(x != null && x.getVal() > 12)
```